# Grouping by and summing in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table in Excel that consists of two columns, Name and Score. The Name column is not unique, many names appear several times. I want to create another table that using formulas groups by name and calculates the total score for each.

So if James had 3 records with scores 2, 8 and 4, the other table would show James with total score 14. How do I do this?

Comment: Since 2+8+4 = 14 not 15, I honestly do not know how you would do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a pivot table. Select the data you want to use and then go to the `Insert` tab on the ribbon and select `Pivot Table`. After the pivot table is created you need to add the `Name` column to the `Rows` section of the pivot table and the `Score` column to the `Values` section. Then change the `Values` calculation from count to sum.